# try to make path in Google maps from JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

I try to make a path in Google Maps ,
firts execute a query and take the result as jeson the query is

```
SELECT  ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom,4326)) As geom, cost FROM table;
```

first i take the coordinates as a json array from php the code of json array is

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $row_array['gid'] = $row['gid'];
        $row_array['cost'] = $row['cost'];
        $row_array['coords'] = json_decode($row['geom'], true);

        array_push($json_response,$row_array);

    }
```

the results from this array is like this

```
[{"gid":null,"cost":"66.1287777511195","coords":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[22.941692442967,40.586863079715],[22.941123079604,40.586455128992]]}},.......,{"gid":null,"cost":"66.0742074916243","coords":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[22.942269084347,40.587264319141],[22.941692442967,40.586863079715]]}}]
```

i try to push in a new array in javascript to plot in map but i can't make it
the code from the java script is 
first take the array from php to javascript with

```
     var jsonAr = <?php echo json_encode($json_response); ?>;
```

And after with this loop i tray to make the LatLng

```
var pathAr = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i < jsonAr.length; i++) {
                  var coords = jsonAr[i].coords.coordinates[0];
            for(var j = 0 ; j < coords.length; j++){
                pathAr.push( new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]));
            }}
```

If some one can help. thanks.

Comment: Your code is not complete (the for is not closed).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pathAr is not defined`

Comment: The loop is closed and the pathAr is difined in the start of the script.
where the loop is not closed ?

Comment: Sorry, your inconsistent indentation was the issue.  Now I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var coords = jsonAr[i].coords.coordinates[0];
```

should be

```
var coords = jsonAr[i].coords.coordinates;
```

---

A different approach, because your data seems to be perfect for use with the data-layer.

Convert it to geoJSON:
(Not tested):

```
<?php
   $json_response=array('type'    =>'FeatureCollection',
                        'features'=>array());

   while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $json_response['features'][]
          = array('type'=>'Feature',
                  'properties'=>array('gid' => $row['gid'],
                                      'cost'=> $row['cost']
                                     ),
                  'geometry'=>json_decode($row['geom'], true)
                );
    }
?>

var jsonAr = <?php echo json_encode($json_response); ?>;
```

To draw the lines simply call:

```
//map ist the google.maps.Map-instance
map.data.addGeoJson(jsonAr);
```

...done, no need to parse `jsonAr`.

The difference: Your approach will draw a single line with all points defined in each item of jsonAr, while my approach will draw a separate line for each item.

Comment: `var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline` you need to use the polilyne to draw ?
how is work with out the Polyline ?

Comment: when you use `addGeoJson` you don't need to create a Polyline, this method will create all the elements(points,lines,polygons) automatically

Comment: Thank you very mach is warking perfect , how can change the color of line i use the `map.data.setStyle({
              fillColor: "#2249a3",
              strokeWeight: 2
              });
     ` but is not change the color of line

Comment: use `strokeColor` instead of `fillColor`

Comment: Can i ask something else , is possible to make an info windows for every part of roads for example the name for every roads and make an icon to across the path and every change in roads show an infowindow to have the name of road which accrosing